# Jquery - Get every style on page and add font size

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to find all styles on page, which are using `font-size: **px` style and set it be bigger or smaller depending of already defined `font-size`?

For example, there is a few blocks:

```
<div class="text1">Text1</div>
<div class="text2">Text2</div>

.text1 {
font-size: 12px;
}
.text2 {
font-size: 16px;
}
```

There is can be any amount of blocks and styles. Lets say we are setting function to get text bigger by 2px, so we will got `font-size: 14px` for `.text1` and `font-size: 18px` for `.text2`

JSFiddle for fast editing: http://jsfiddle.net/8BbHP/

Comment: Yes, you set the font sizes on your page in `em`, then you use a font size in percent on the body tag to change them all.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But this will not work for px, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use better class structure to make it easier to achieve your goal, like below:

```
<div class="text text1">Text1</div>
<div class="text text2">Text2</div>

.text1 {
font-size: 12px;
}
.text2 {
font-size: 16px;
}
```

By doing so, you can easily get all element with class `text` and change the `font-size`, like below:

```
$(".text").each(function(){
    var current_size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
    $(this).css("font-size", current_size + 2 + "pt");
})
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8BbHP/1/)....

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I think that will solve my problem!